# Swing stack trace with no line information where it's failing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, stack-trace

I'm working with Swing, and it's giving me this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsButtonUI.getXPButtonState(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsButtonUI.paintXPButtonBackground(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsButtonUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried debugging but it's failing in the `Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0]` in the `EventDispatchThread.pumoEventsForFiler(int, Conditional, EventFilter) line:not available`

I'm not really quite sure where to go from with this. Could someone explain how to do with stack traces with no line information?

EDIT:
Basically I tried to do MVC in Swing and my ButtonModel was atrocious. So I deleted it and the problem went away. I would post my code but Eclipse isn't bringing the file back. My button still doesn't work but that's a completely new issue.

Comment: In this situation the only way is to switch to a jdk which was compiled *with* line information.

Comment: I don't know where the error is coming from, so I don't really know what code to post

Comment: Do happen to do something funky with a button? If so, post that code ...

Comment: How do I switch to a jdk compiled with line information? O.o

Comment: I don’t know of any jdk without. Check your project settings inside eclipse to use a jdk, not a jre.

Answer (score 5):

When you don’t have the line, it sometimes help to look at the entire method to look what *could* be the possible situation. In your case there seems to be only one possible cause: you have set the model of a button to `null`. It seems that Swing’s button class allows this, but the Windows look and feel does not check for this.

Comment: +1 I have reached the same conclusion. I don't know the contract for `model`, though: is it set automatically or what.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: there is a default model set initially. Usually, you don’t change it as it implements the desired behavior of being, e.g. a push button, radio button or toggle. The application specific behavior is typically implemented via the `Action` interface.